# Использование Ansible в процессе сборки

Tags: ansible, непрерывная-интеграция

Не нашлись истории успеха по данному вопросу, потому интересуюсь тут.

> Цель: получить механизм полного воспроизводства процесса сборки на
>   локальной машине и абстрагироваться от конкретной **CI** системы.

Сейчас процесс сборки описывется встроенными *CI Tasks*, которые представляют тот или иной шаг:

- извлечь исходный код;
- получить версию из **git** тега;
- запустить утилиту для сборки;
- etc.

---

> Можно использовать самописный скрипт, который будет являться заменой
>   описанных выше шагов. Главный минус видится в том, что подобное
>   решение превратится в полноценное программирование, откуда будет
>   вытекать:

- проблема сопровождения, так как это программирование;
- увеличение времени на понимание для вновь прибывших людей.

---

> Можно использовать **Ansible**, так как он предлагает довольно простой
>   синтаксис описания задач, имеет множество модулей, которые заменили бы
>   множество строчек самописных скриптов.

Т.е на выходе мы достигнем цели и избежим вышеописанных проблем.

---

Однако тут проблема с концептуальной `(а может и технической)` точки зрения, так как **Ansible** хорош в проблемах конфигурирования, развертывания, а описывать процессы сборки как-то не вписывается в его задачи.

---

- целесообразно ли использовать данный инструмент для описанных целей?
- какие имеются концептуальные/технические проблемы?

---

> Нет задачи изобрести свою **CI** систему, однако хочется в
>   затронутом процессе как можно меньше описания шагов с ее стороны.

Comment: Ну...Для деплоя Ansible хорош. Т.е. установить git, запулить, ветки настроить и т.п. Но сам процесс сборки, скорей всего, будет bash скриптом, который будет вызываться в каком-то такск Ansible, что не очень-то рекомендуется делать.

Comment: @Suvitruf, Я думал не затрагивать конкретные среды, но допустим речь идет о `.NET` платформе, проект собирается с помощью MSBuild, т.е и сборка описывается посредством `MSBuild Scripts`. Что плохого в том, что `MSBuild` будет вызываться из `Ansible` (win_command какой-нибудь), а не из `CI` Task? В обоих случая надо будет указать директорию с `MSBuild`, только в случае с `CI (bamboo)` в `Task` я выберу тип `Builder` и конкретную версию сборщика, которую сам же указывал. Нечто аналогичное будет и в случае скрипта.

Comment: @Suvitruf, `что не очень-то рекомендуется делать` - Что-то упустил. Где почитать? Как аргументируют?

Comment: https://www.ansible.com/blog/ansible-best-practices-essentials "4. Use Modules Before Run Commands" Велик шанс, что при повторном запуске при использовании bash тасков что-то перестанет работать.

Comment: @Suvitruf, беря во внимание выше описанный случай, то при работе с одной и той же версией кода результат будет детерминированный. Разве нет?

Comment: Вероятно. Суть тут в том, что чем больше неизвестных в систему вводишь, тем ниже детерминированность. Таски только с использованием Ansible модулей лучше, чем таски с использование каши из модулей, bash скриптов и т.п. Но это не значит, что не надо использовать bash скрипты, просто они ведут себя порой неконсистентно.

Comment: Хотели абстрагироваться от конкретной CI - пришли к тому, что завязались на конкретный ansible/chef/puppet. И чем-то это лучше, м? Вы именно изобретаете собственную CI систему, из ansible и палок.

Comment: @AK, миграция с одной системы на другую будет проходить проще. Используя Ansible, я создаю некоторую абстракцию над процессом, появляется независимость от систем и их специфичного функционала - избавляемся от вендор лока.

Comment: Я люблю ansible, но я считаю, что всегда плохо создавать лишние абстракции. Свой логгер поверх log4net/nlog, свои надстройки над EF, свои надстройки над CI. Вы потратите в два раза больше времени на настройку собственной системы на ansible, чем понадобится на переход с CI на CI.

Comment: @AK, думаю подобный подход может пойти на пользу в плане взаимодействия внутри комманды, в том смысле, что если потребуются изменения в процессе, то можно это делать посредством pull request и т.п. Как с кодом, так и с процессом сборки.

Comment: @AK, понятно, что лишние абстракции это плохо, но где эта грань? `на настройку собственной системы` я не пытаюсь создать новую систему, я хочу использовать Ansible для описания шагов сборки.

Answer (score 0):

> проблема сопровождения, так как это программирование;

Ansible tasks / playbooks / roles **не решает проблему сопровождения**. Также, как и код, **обязательно надо тестировать**.

> увеличение времени на понимание для вновь прибывших людей.

Ansible **не уменьшает время на понимание**, даже иногда наоборот - [Пример](https://github.com/AfsmNGhr/devops-swarm-mode/blob/master/.github/workflows/main.yml#L40-L44)

Реализовал bash обертки над **ansible playbooks**. (Да-да, **не best practice**, нужен **ansible module**, но **сложность** его **не уменьшится**)

> целесообразно ли использовать данный инструмент для описанных целей?

Да, если **польза > риска**. Начал использовать именно **для build**, когда появился проект с компиляцией и кучей **ENV VARS**.

Было `ENV` c переменными в `.env`файл. Стало `ANSIBLE_VAULT_PASS` и подстановка **secrets** в build / deploy.

> какие имеются концептуальные/технические проблемы?

Может не быть модулей. **Писать самим** или писать shell вызовы (**не best practice**).

**Разберем на примере: docker build**

Есть модуль [docker_image](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/modules/docker_image_module.html). Вполне билдит image, но явно муторно описывать каждый image.

Дальше [docker_compose](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/modules/docker_compose_module.html) и билдит, и запускает. Без проблем? Нет, модуль падает при работе с `DOCKER_HOST` via `ssh://username@host:port`.

Или **на примере запросов** `POST`.

Придется использовать **curl** или **писать module**.

> Не нашлись истории успеха по данному вопросу

Вполне успешно работает - [build role](https://github.com/AfsmNGhr/devops-swarm-mode/blob/master/ansible/roles/build/tasks/main.yml)